# Concatenate variable with leading zeroes with another string

Tags: excel, vba, string-concatenation

**Scenario**

I have an excel cell that contains value with leading zereos (Eg: 0002). My macro is copying this value to a variable called `runNumber` and pasting it into another file by concatenating this `runNumber` with some other string. But when it does that, I am missing the leading zeros of `runNumber`

**Codes**

`yearInYy = "19"`

`ciNumber = "PFTPA-" & yearInYy & "-" & runNumber`

Output cell showing as `PFTPA-19-2`

**What I need**

I need the output cell to show

`PFTPA-19-0002`

Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ciNumber = "PFTPA-" & yearInYy & "-" & Format(runNumber, "0000")
```

Using the [`Format` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications), you can convert a date or number to a string with a specific format.  All we do here is require 4 digits, with leading zeros.

The equivalent in Excel itself is the [`TEXT` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c)

Answer (score 2):

In order to add leading zeroes to a string, you don't need VBA, you can use following Excel formula for this:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT("0";4-LEN(D4));D4)
```

It works as follows:

- Take the length of your string, and subtract this from 4 (it will give you the number of "0" characters you need).
- Create a string, which consists of a repetition of "0" characters.
- Concatenate that repetition of strings to your original string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the field containing the 0002 is formatted as a text field then work with strings throughout. Here I am reading runNumber from cell A1. This means you can deal with a variable number of leading zeroes.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim runNumber As String, yearInYy As String, ciNumber As String
    yearInYy = "19"
    runNumber = [A1]
    ciNumber = "PFTPA-" & yearInYy & "-" & runNumber
    Debug.Print ciNumber
End Sub
```

Comment: Issue with your method is, I need to pre format cells of the source as text which I don't wish to. Answer from another person above will not format cells of source text and instead, it format the variable into 0000 form. I prefer to do that way. Thanks for your effort. By the way just curious what is that [A1] means? Does it mean Range("A1").value?

Comment: I was trying to cater for the fact you can have variable number of zeroes and there is no statement that that number will always be the same length. Also, if that cell is not text formatted how do you have the 000 at the front as per your description? [] it’s an alternative notation for range so range A1.

Comment: It is still possible without formatting the cell. I am able to do it with the help from another person here in stackoverflow. it is working by following this code   `ciNumber = "PFTPA-" & yearInYy & "-" & Format(runNumber, "0000")`

Comment: What I am saying is that you said you have 0002 in the cell. How are the zeroes present if the cell is not formatted? If you had just 2 in the cell and wanted 0002 that would be different. You can also use Format$ rather than Format for minor efficiency gains.

Comment: oh yea..correct. My bad. I asked that way in the question. But when I see a method without any pre cell formatting, I preferred that way.

Comment: That’s alright :-) note my point about typed function Format$

Comment: Sure will do. Format$ is reducing calculation time slightly, isn't it?

Comment: In this case you won’t notice but in principal yes. Certainly if using in long loop for example. Just worth being aware of.